# good json format in awk

Tags: json, awk, output

I've been searching through the net but can't find solution to my awk printing output.

This is my awk (END code for printing):

```
END {
for ( j = 1; j <= i; j++ )
{ print "{\"name\": \"%s\",\"address\": \"%s\", \"email\": \"%s\" },\n",
name, address, email
}
   }' "$file"
```

Which apparently, results to this output:

```
  {"name": "Kimberly":"AMAZON", "address":"NY", "email":"kim@example.com" },
  {"name": "Manny","address": "Nashville", "email": "manny@example.com" },
  {"name": "Nina","address": "Mountain Hills", "email": "iamnina@example.com" },
```

But I want to generate an output like this:

```
[
  {"name": "Kimberly":"AMAZON", "address":"NY", "email":"kim@example.com"},                 
  {"name":"Manny","address": "Nashville", "email": "manny@example.com" }, 
  {"name": "Nina","address": "Mountain Hills", "email": "iamnina@example.com" }]
```

I hope anyone can help.
Thank you very in advance.

Comment: Please confirm that your awk code is producing the presented output...

Comment: I didn't even know you could use print like that, is it not supposed to be printf

Comment: please don't [cross-posting question](http://askubuntu.com/q/573155/283843)

Comment: @KasiyA: I didn't mean to do such thing. I thought my question posted on the other site was not working. Later did I know that I made duplicate questions already. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question i am assuming that you only want the formatting.

So here is one way you could do it

```
END{print "["
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    print "{\"name\": \""name"\", \"address\":\""address"\", \"email\":\""email"\"}"(j==i?"]":",")}
```

Print the first `[`
Then print the lines, using the ternary operator to check if it is the last line and printing `]` when it is, otherwise print `,`.